# Eclipse Package Explorer Unrecognized Package

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna, package-explorer

I am trying to open a src folder in java.
One of the main sub folder is not being intepreted as a package icon in the package explorer.
The others are fine, only the first one. (Please see image below)
I checked all the java class inside the folder and they have the proper package declaration.

Do any of you have an idea?

[image]

Comment: The image means 'package only containing non Java resources'

Comment: @greg-449 yes, I checked all the other folder and it only contains java and class files like the other folders.